# HashMap "method put() is undefined for the type HashMap"

Tags: java, debugging, dictionary, hashmap, undefined

I programmed the following into Eclipse but the program keeps giving me the error: `The method put(String, String) is undefined for the type HashMap.`As far as I know, `put()` is the correct method to use to input values into a `HashMap`. Can anyone please help me debug this problem?

```
import java.util.HashMap; 
public class MapTester 
{ 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
     HashMap <String, String>hm = new HashMap <String, String>(); 
      hm.put("type", "56.09"); 
      hm.put("call", "PHONE"); 
      hm.put("what", "PHONE"); 
      System.out.println(hm.toString());
} 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my end. Is this your whole code?

Comment: I compiled and executed it without any problem.  It prints out `{call=PHONE, what=PHONE, type=56.09}`.  *tested with JRE6*

Comment: check your java library may be it corrupted. better you re-install your system jre

Comment: Yes, it is. That's what's so confusing for me. Theoretically, this should work perfect. Could it be something wrong with my version of Eclipse?

Comment: I'll try re-installing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build and run the program ignoring what eclipse says about it. Does it run? If not, what the compiler outputs? If in doubt try to build it via command-line.

Eclipse (and Netbeans too) may get confused about some things in the code sometimes due to stale caches, incomplete analysis, classpath problems and a lot of other things.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `import` statements.  Perhaps you are importing a `HashMap` class from some other library?  It should be `java.util.HashMap`.